# How to remove render blocking css file

Tags: css, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

PageSpeed Insights says I have to Optimize display for CSS as follows:
/wp-content/themes/my-theme/fonts.css?family=
How do I remove the render blocking css file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the request to get your css files after the page is loaded, which i don't recommand.

the recommanded way is:

1. inline your css in your html
2. use webpack to build your scripts and css (recommanded)

if your css is too large, then you need to inline the css required to render the above the fold area (visible area to the user) on top of your page (in the head) and defer loading the remaining css until the above the fold area is rendered.